# Troubleshooting an Electrical Circuit - Is This an Expected Voltage Drop?

Tags: voltage-measurement, troubleshooting

I am troubleshooting an electrical problem and am having trouble understanding the readings I am seeing on my digital multimeter.  I am a DIYer with just the basics of electrical engineering knowledge, but would appreciate comments on what I am seeing and the physics behind it.  Would this be expected based on Ohm's law?

Below is a schematic of my circuit which supports three electric baseboard radiators controlled by a single wall mounted thermostat.  The heat had stopped working and when I removed the thermostat I found 2 tiny baby mice in the electrical box!  After removing the mice I wanted to test to see if there might be any anomalies indicating chewed wire damage inside the wall and got the voltage readings shown on the diagram.

For those outside of the US and Canada, note that we get 220V by going across the two 110V wires from the line source, whereas our 110V is done by going from one of the two 110V sources to the neutral.  So I understand the 120V reading on the first measurement.

I am not clear however as to why I got the other two readings.  Note that all of these readings were taken with the thermostat switch open.

My question:  Are the 20V and 70V readings I am seeing to be expected voltage drops due to the resistance of the radiators?  Or could it be an indication of some line damage hidden in the walls?

[image: Simplified circuit schematic]

Comment: Yes, there is a missing connection to the radiators. The voltages you see are probably just from capacitive coupling between wires.

Comment: Is there anything else connected? Do the heaters have electronic thermostats?

Comment: Connect some load (e.g. a lamp) in parallel to the voltmeter input.

Comment: your question is a better fit at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Thanks, @jsotola, I will repost at diy.stackexchange.com/questions. I had thought this question might require a little better theoretical understanding of circuits than most DIYers or electricians generally deal with.

Comment: electricians deal with exactly this kind of issues

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other connections to the circuit you should see the full 220 VAC across the open switch. With an open thermostat switch there should be no current drawn, so there should be no voltage drop in the radiators. That's what would happen if the circuits were intact.

What's most likely is that there is an open circuit so the 70 V and 20 V readings are just capacitive coupling and there's either no connection to the 220 V through the radiators or there's a very high resistance in that side of the circuit.